# Optimizing a Kafka Streams Application with Multiple Sub-Topologies

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm running a Kafka Streams application with three sub-topologies. The stages of activity are roughly as follows:

1. `stream` Topic A
2. `selectKey` and repartition Topic A `to` Topic B
3. `stream` Topic B
4. `foreach` Topic B to Topic C `Producer`
5. `stream` Topic C
6. Topic C `to` Topic D

Topics A, B, and C are each materialized, which means that if each topic has 40 partitions, my maximum parallelism is 120.

At first I was running 5 streams applications with 8 threads a piece. With this set up I was experiencing inconsistent performance. It seems like some sub-topologies sharing the same thread were hungrier for CPU than others and after a while, I'd get this error: `Member [client_id] in group [consumer_group] has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)`. Everything would get rebalanced, which could lead to decreased performance until the next failure and rebalance.

My questions are as follows:

1. How is it that multiple sub-topologies are able to be run on a single thread? A poll queue?
2. How does each thread decide how to allocate compute resources to each of its sub-topologies?
3. How do you optimize your thread to topic-partition ratio in such cases to avoid periodic consumer failures? e.g., will a 1:1 ratio ensure more consistent performance?
4. If you use a 1:1 ratio, how do you ensure that every thread gets assigned its own topic-partition and some threads aren't left idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The thread will poll() for all topics of different sub-topologies and check the records `topic` metadata to feed it into the correct task.
2. Each sub-topology is treated the same, ie, available resources are evenly distributed if you wish.
3. A 1:1 ratio is only useful if you have enough cores. I would recommend to monitor your CPU utilization. If it's too high (larger >80%) you should add more cores/threads.
4. Kafka Streams handles this for you automatically.

Couple of general comments:

- you might consider to increase `max.poll.interval.ms` config to avoid that a consumer drops out of the group
- you might consider to decrease `max.poll.records` to get less records per `poll()` call, and thus decrease the time between two consecutive calls to `poll()`.
- note, that `max.poll.records` does not imply increases network/broker communication -- if a single fetch request return more records than `max.poll.records` config, the data is just buffered within the consumer and the next `poll()` will be served from the buffered data avoiding a broker round trip

Comment: It was my understanding that `max.poll.interval.ms` is set by default to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which should be around 25 days. I'm not setting this in my configuration, but consumer groups were being dropped well before 25 days anyway.

Comment: Depends on the version you are using. You can double check the used value in the logs.

Comment: re answer 4: I've found that this isn't always true (for version 1.1). sometimes I have to reboot a streams app to get all threads to pick up partitions, but maybe that should be another question.